# Is it possible to detect visual studio version in compiled .net assembly?

Tags: .net

I have a .net exe file I want to find out which version of visual studio is used to compile the assembly.. Is there are any solution to find out the IDE version.?

Comment: Can you tell us why you would like to know that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Visual Studio for building. Visual Studio depends on MSBuild instead.

Anyway, you can try [Detect It Easy](https://github.com/horsicq/Detect-It-Easy), it should give you linker version that can be paired with MSBuild version and Visual Studio version.